# injection doesnt work in spookyjs

Tags: node.js, spookyjs

```
    try {
     var Spooky = require('spooky');
    } catch (e) {
     var Spooky = require('../lib/spooky');
    }

    var spooky = new Spooky({
     child: {
      transport: 'http'
     },
     casper: {
     logLevel: 'debug',
     verbose: true,
     clientScripts: ["abc.js"]
     }
    }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
     e = new Error('Failed to initialize SpookyJS');
     e.details = err;
     throw e;
    }

    spooky.start("http://www.google.com");

    spooky.then(function(){
     this.evaluate(function() {
     console.log("testing");
     var x = abc.check();
     console.log("x: "+x);
     });
    });

    spooky.run();
    });

    spooky.on('console', function (line) {
     console.log(line);
    });

    spooky.on('remote.message', function(message) {
    console.log('[Inside Evaluate] ' + message);
    );
```

My output is:

```
    [info] [phantom] Starting...
    [info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
    [debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.google.com/, HTTP GET
    [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested:         url=https://www.google.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
    [debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZIXqVvXoGuHI8AeX06uYAg, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
    [debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZIXqVvXoGuHI8AeX06uYAg"
    [debug] [phantom] Automatically injected /Users/BitBucket/headless_browser/abc.js client side
    [debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
    [debug] [phantom] start page is loaded
    [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=ZIXqVvXoGuHI8AeX06uYAg (HTTP 200)
    end of
    [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 1037ms.
    remote message caught: testing
    [info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 1055ms
```

I cant see the value of x. Only the text before the function is displayed which is "testing". I have injected the file in casper options only and the function is exported in the js file. I have tried entering the absolute path also.

Comment: Please share the contents of abc.js in your post

Comment: i found the answer. You must just call the function without the file name.